# Error on Google Cloud - Genomics: "API solution not found with service name: genomics"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-genomics, rna-seq

I am completely new to the HPC and Google Cloud (I just signed for a trial account) .

My Idea is to perform a RNAseq analysis (9 samples paired, 18 fastQ files), Mainly I want to perform the FastQC and the mapping trying different aligments. Download the Bam files and continue from home with my computer.

First, I generated a instance with 8 vCPU and the max memory they allow me, and I choose Ubuntu 18.04.

Then I went to genomics API, and the firs error came up:

API solution not found with service name: genomics

How can I progress? Is it possible to do what I want in the trial period?

Regards,
Fer

Answer (score 1):

Per the Google Cloud [Genomics Quickstart Guide](https://cloud.google.com/genomics/docs/quickstart), you will need to [Enable Billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project) for the account, and then can [enable the Genomics API](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=genomics.googleapis.com) for your project.

You can use these products with trial credits, but they will require a billing account to be created to use the trial credits.